# #1111 - Invalid use of group function error in sql

Tags: sql, select, sum, mysql-error-1111

Does anyone know a solution for this error: 
 #1111 - Invalid use of group function

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT leerlingen.leerlingnummer, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, klas, leerlingen.bestemming 
FROM betalingen, leerlingen, bestemmingen
WHERE leerlingen.leerlingnummer = betalingen.leerlingnummer AND SUM( betalingen.bedrag ) > bestemmingen.bedrag
GROUP BY leerlingen.leerlingnummer
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference the results of an aggregate function (SUM) in predicated query (WHERE), you will have to specify the aggregate in the select, then use a "[Having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)" clause to filter that set.